# JS if condition alert

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, alerts

I just have php function that I would like to return alert messages using JS alert box.

When I just do the first if condition the alert works fine.  But once I add the others the alert box won't work (==2 and 3).

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

```
$(document).ready( function() {

if (<?php echo error_for('fileTmpLoc') ?>==1)
{
alert("Error: No image was selected.");
}
if (<?php echo error_for('fileTmpLoc') ?>==2)
{
alert("Error: Your file was too large. It was larger than 3.5 Megabytes in size.");
}
if (<?php echo error_for('fileTmpLoc') ?>==3)
{
alert("Error: Your file is too small. It was smaller than 200 KB in size.");
}
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also handle the error conditional checking and JS alert output via PHP, eg:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
<?php 
    switch(error_for('fileTmpLoc')) {
        case 1 : echo 'alert("Error: No image was selected.");';
                 break;
        case 2 : echo 'alert("Error: Your file was too large. It was larger than 3.5 Megabytes in size.");';
                 break;
        case 3 : echo 'alert("Error: Your file is too small. It was smaller than 200 KB in size.");';
                 break;
    }
?>
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help guys!  Flauntster that worked like a charm! Joe Marie...else if didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't test this, but did you tried using if else statement?

```
$(document).ready( function() {

if (<?php echo error_for('fileTmpLoc') ?>==1)
{
   alert("Error: No image was selected.");
}
else if (<?php echo error_for('fileTmpLoc') ?>==2)
{
   alert("Error: Your file was too large. It was larger than 3.5 Megabytes in size.");
}
else if (<?php echo error_for('fileTmpLoc') ?>==3)
{
   alert("Error: Your file is too small. It was smaller than 200 KB in size.");
}

});
```